# How do I get 1M instead of 1m using numeral.js?

Tags: javascript, numeral.js

```
 import numeral from 'numeral'
        formatNumber (x) {
         return numeral(rawOnlineTotal).format('0a');
        }
formatNumber(10000000);  

expected output: 1M  
Actual Output: 1m
```

formatNumber(1000);
    expected output: 1K
    Actual Output: 1k

Comment: Tried using format('0A') but didn't work.

Comment: Call `.toUpperCase()` on the result?

Comment: Sweet!
That works.
Thanks.